# Use multiprocessing to accelerate Dataframe append

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have been research on how to use multiprocess to accelerate my pandas function.
And the reason why I only looking for multiprocessing is because of environment constraint
I found that most of the discussion was long time before,so I open this disscussion
Here's some of the method I have tried but didn't come with good results.

1. Dask(My company's server didn't support the environment)
2. [`multiprocesspandas`](https://github.com/akhtarshahnawaz/multiprocesspandas), however it seems like the packages only to acceralate calculation instead of multiprocess append
3. Parquet

```
def generate_feature(thres, high):

    one_path = './data/all_pattern/1st_mask_data'
    train_files= glob.glob(one_path+"/*.csv")


    df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for f in train_files:
        print('current train_files process:',f)
        df2 = pd.read_csv(f)
        df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)


    if(high):
        df = df[(df['label(V)'] >= thres)]
    else:
        df = df[(df['label(V)'] < thres)]
        
    X_train = df[['Internal_power', 'Switching_power']]
    y_train = df['label(V)']

    print("X_train", X_train.shape)
    print("y_train", y_train.shape)
    
    return X_train, y_train
```

After that I call my function to get my training data

```
X_train, y_train = generate_feature(0,1)
```

It's an very easy code, and most time consuming issues I believe happens at **append method** which iterate over billions time I believe, and each of the dataframe don't need to consider order, It takes over an hour to prepare one training data.

I think there might has an easy way to multiprocess the for loop , I just couldn't figure it out by using pool/map from python multiprocessing.

Last, I know because of GIL I need to call the function in the main function. The above code is just to demo what I am trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball says multiprocessing reading and appending the df will not help you very much, since you'll still spend time in serializing the df between processes, plus the parent process would also spend time appending the dfs into one.

However, the full process here could be easily multiprocessable, since

- filtering using `thres` could be done for each CSV file separately
- converting the filtered data to training vectors/matrices could be done for each file separately

That way all the main process would need to do is concatenate raw Numpy matrices, which should be quite efficient. This could probably be even more efficient if the preprocessing is done onto disk instead of "paying the serialization tax" with multiprocessing's return values.

Comment: Thanks for yor reply, still need some time to understand your suggestion

Comment: Also, the reason why I think multiprocess might works is because I got like over 100 csv files , the for loop iterate each csv files take the data i need and then append it together I am thinkg if I can let each processor deal with one csv files, wouldn't this solve my issues?

Comment: No, because it's likely that reading the CSV is cheap but you'd then "pay" a lot of serialization and deserialization overhead to have the full dataframe sent to the main process, which then again spends a lot of time (in a single process!) to do concatenation for a large dataset, which you only _afterwards_ cut off to the data you need. As I explain in the answer, it's better for the parallel child processes to do all of the parallel work they can, and only do as little serial work as possible afterwards.

Comment: so this is why most of the disussion , for example the github I post , they mainly focus on multiprocess calculation?

Comment: At a quick glance, that repo/library will also have you pay the serialization/deserialization prices.

Answer (score 0):

```
def generate_feature(path1):


    train_files = glob.glob( '/*.csv')

    X_train, y_train = cell_based_tile_based(train_files)


    print("X_train", X_train.shape)
    print("y_train", y_train.shape)


    return X_train, y_train




def read_csv(filename):

    return pd.read_csv(filename)

def cell_based_tile_based(train_files):


    cpu_num = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    with Pool(processes=cpu_num) as pool: 

        df_list = pool.map(read_csv, train_files)
        combined_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)




    X_train = combined_df[['f1','f2']]
    y_train = combined_df['label']

    return X_train, y_train
```

Here's how i solve my own question, Hope will work for you guys